# C# How to go through an array using Parallel.Foreach but not checking every element

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

```
public static ConcurrentBag<Point3d> scale_and_sort_out(double max_dep)
{
    var results = new ConcurrentBag<Point3d>();
    Parallel.ForEach(cameraSpacePoints, currentPoint =>
    {
        Point3d pt = new Point3d();
        if (currentPoint.Z > max_dep)
        {
            return;
        }

        else 
        {
            if (System.Single.IsNegativeInfinity(currentPoint.X) == false)
            {

                pt.X = -currentPoint.Z * 1000 ;
                pt.Y = -currentPoint.X * 1000 ;
                pt.Z = currentPoint.Y * 1000  ;

                results.Add(pt);
            }

            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }

    });

    return results;
}
```

Above is my code to go through the array `cameraSpacePoints`. Currently it is checking every single element in the array, but I want to check every i_th element : `for (int i = 0; i < cameraSpacePoints.Length; i += res)` Will this be possible with `Parallel.ForEach` ?

Comment: Will `Parallel.ForEach(cameraSpacePoints.Where((x, i) => i % n == 0), ...` do for that?

Comment: @Bleep-Bloop it should, it's simply preselecting the indexes to be dealt with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also consider a [Parallel.For](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-for-loop):

```
Parallel.For(0, cameraSpacePoints.Length, index => { 
     if (index % i != 0)
         return; 

     //do stuff
 });
```